# After run selenium python script for login not show proper result

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, web

I am new in selenium and python also.
When I run selenium python script then user show **login** but it not show proper page i.e **home page**.

```html
# create a new Firefox session
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.maximize_window()

# navigate to the application home pageMy Account
driver.get("http://betaserverapp.com/es/en/Home")

button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('login_a')
button.click()

#Username
username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
username.clear()
username.send_keys("pradnya@appristine.in")
username.submit()

#Password
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password.clear()
password.send_keys("123456")
password.submit()

#click on button
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/button')
button.click()
```

[image]

Comment: thats not  selenium fault probably.Have you tried entering it manually by adding details and press Enter key at password field??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that [`submit` will trigger the submission of the whole form](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=submit). Just delete those two `submit` and let `button.click()` do the job.